# Android Accelerometer Getting issue while applying tilled correction to sense data to detect variation in Z axis

Tags: java, android, matrix, coordinates, accelerometer

I need to detect the variation in Z axis of android device for this I'm using 3-axis accelerometer, where x1 and y1 are the horizontal components and z1 is the vertical component of sensed acceleration signal on some tilled state of the device.

Now assuming idle case when the 3-axis accelerometer rests on a flat horizontal surface, it can sense gravitational acceleration from the earth, in this situation,

```
z1 = g = 9.8 

x1 = y1 = 0
```

The direction of the gravitational acceleration is absolute, so it can be used to calculate the tilt angle of the accelerometer.

the tilt angle 'angleX' is related to x1 and z1 and I'm finding it using the below equation:

```
double angleX = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x1, z1));
```

the tilt angle 'angleY' is related to y1 and z1 and I'm using the below equation to find it:

```
 double angleY = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y1, z1));
```

Considering the case of tilt along both the x and y directions, I'm combining (1) and (2) to obtain real horizontal and vertical components, noted as x2, y2, and
z2.

Using the following equations to correct the sensed acceleration:

```
 double x2 = x1 - (9.8 * Math.sin(angleX));
 double y2 = y1 - (9.8 * Math.sin(angleY));
 double z2 = z1 - (9.8 * Math.cos(angleX) * Math.cos(angleY));
```

Now when I'm testing the idle case with the above approach and using my values as follow

```
x1=0
y1=0
z1=9.8
```

It means there should no tilled correction require

```
public static void testCase() {
        float[] values = {0, 0, 9.8f};
        tilledCorrection(values);
    }

    public static double[] tilledCorrection(float[] values) {
        float x1 = values[0];
        float y1 = values[1];
        float z1 = values[2];
        double angleX = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x1, z1));
        double angleY = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y1, z1));
        double x2 = x1 - (9.8 * Math.sin(angleX));
        double y2 = y1 - (9.8 * Math.sin(angleY));
        double z2 = z1 - (9.8 * Math.cos(angleX) * Math.cos(angleY));

        Log.e("", "x2=" + x2);
        Log.e("", "y2=" + y2);
        Log.e("", "z2=" + z2);

        Log.e("", "angleX=" + angleX);
        Log.e("", "angleY=" + angleY);

        return new double[]{x2, y2, z2};
    }
```

output

x2=0.0

y2==0.0

z2=1.9073486

angleX=0.0

angleY=0.0

I do not have any idea why my z axis changed when there is no change in rest two axis and it is case of idle state.

What all I need to do is finding the variation in z axis if device is not in idle state we'll apply tilled correction to get accurate sense value.

Please suggest any link or guideline

Thanks in advance